For loop through specific columns of table and pass to relational SQL statement
I want to loop through columns ['A', 'B', 'C'] and pass the column names to a select statement in SQL, such as
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE table_name.`A` IS NULL

Thus each select statement would yield a result set based on the column name. This would be contained in a sql script. I would then read each result through a python DB connection, such as mysql-connector. How would I go about doing this? Thank you!
Edit - I want to keep the solution strictly within SQL.

You should listen to the folks who recommend to do this in a Python loop. I don't recommend using a stored procedure, because you'll have to learn about cursors and dynamic queries and fetching multi-results and nonsense like that. Then you'll learn that MySQL procedures don't have a debugger or modules or atomic deployment or good documentation. Trust us — it'll be easier doing the loop in Python. Life's too short to waste it developing MySQL stored procedures.

If you want to keep the solution strictly in sql, then why is your question tagged with python?

@BillKarwin my actual table is large, few TBs of data. The query itself is also not as simple as the one I posted. That's why I figured it would be better to have a pure SQL solution.

You should ask a question with proper details about the problem you are trying to solve. It's still not clear why you need a pure SQL solution. There are details we have no way to know unless you explain them.

"yield a result set based on the column name" what does that look like?  how do you envision the server separating the results for different columns or the client knowing what result is what?  there's nothing impossible here, but you don't show us what it is you want.  remember that sql selects are designed to return rows that contain columns, there are various ways to make information fit that, but you have to tell us what you are expecting

Maybe you could read all your data from database and generate sql commands. If I got it right you need formated sql commands to fetch the data where individual columns IS NULL.
Lets create two tables to work with :
--    S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table tbl_1 ( id Int, a Varchar(12), b Varchar(12), c Decimal );
Insert Into tbl_1 VALUES ( 1, 'ABCD', 'EFGH', 3.5 ), 
                         ( 2, 'OPQR',  Null,  1.2 ), 
                         ( 3, Null,   'STUV', 7.1 ),
                         ( 4, 'KLMN', 'WXYZ', Null);

Create Table tbl_2 ( id Int, x Varchar(12), y Varchar(12), z Varchar(12) );
Insert Into tbl_2 VALUES ( 1, 'XX',  'YY', '*' ), 
                         ( 2, 'AA', Null,  '**' ), 
                         ( 3, Null,  'BB', '***'),
                         ( 4, 'CC',  'DD', Null);

... column names in your tables could be fetched FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WITH
  tbl_cols AS
    ( SELECT   TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION
      FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_schema_name' 
               /* And TABLE_NAME = tbl_1 (if you want just that table) */
      ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION 
    ), 

... create cte to generate sql SELECT command for every column (id column is excluded in this answer)
  cmds AS
    ( Select Row_Number() Over(Order By TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION) as id, 
             TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, 
             Concat( 'Select ', TABLE_NAME, '.*',  
                     ' From ', TABLE_NAME,
                     ' Where ', TABLE_NAME, '.', COLUMN_NAME, ' Is Null'
                   ) as SQL_CMD
      From   tbl_cols
      Where  COLUMN_NAME != 'id'  /* filtering columns here */
    ) 

... get the data from above cte
Select * 
From   cmds;

/*    R e s u l t : 
id  TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME  SQL_CMD
--  ----------  -----------  --------------------------------------------------
1   tbl_1       a            Select tbl_1.* From tbl_1 Where tbl_1.a Is Null
2   tbl_1       b            Select tbl_1.* From tbl_1 Where tbl_1.b Is Null
3   tbl_1       c            Select tbl_1.* From tbl_1 Where tbl_1.c Is Null
4   tbl_2       x            Select tbl_2.* From tbl_2 Where tbl_2.x Is Null
5   tbl_2       y            Select tbl_2.* From tbl_2 Where tbl_2.y Is Null
6   tbl_2       z            Select tbl_2.* From tbl_2 Where tbl_2.z Is Null        */

... above is set of sql commands defined for each table having a column specific sql code ...
Furthermore, if you create another cte that will collect above sql commands and union them for the same table then you could get all the table data that specific sql commands would fetch ...
  cmds_union AS
    ( SELECT   TABLE_NAME, 
               for_columns, 
               REPLACE(SubStr(SQL_CMD, 1, Length(SQL_CMD) - 11), ',', '') as SQL_CMD
      FROM   
      ( Select   TABLE_NAME, 
                 GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) as for_columns,
                 GROUP_CONCAT(SQL_CMD, ' UNION ALL
' )  as SQL_CMD
        From     cmds 
        Group By TABLE_NAME
      ) a
    )
Select * 
From   cmds_union;

/*      R e s u l t : 
TABLE_NAME  for_columns  SQL_CMD
----------  -----------  -------------------------------------------------------
tbl_1       a,b,c        Select tbl_1.* From tbl_1 Where tbl_1.a Is Null UNION ALL
                         Select tbl_1.* From tbl_1 Where tbl_1.b Is Null UNION ALL
                         Select tbl_1.* From tbl_1 Where tbl_1.c Is Null
                         
tbl_2       x,y,z        Select tbl_2.* From tbl_2 Where tbl_2.x Is Null UNION ALL
                         Select tbl_2.* From tbl_2 Where tbl_2.y Is Null UNION ALL
                         Select tbl_2.* From tbl_2 Where tbl_2.z Is Null              */

See the fiddle here.
NOTE:
You can filter tables/columns of interest and/or adjust the code to better fit your needs. This is just a possible option to do it strictly using sql.

Construct the query dynamically in Python in a loop.
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']

for col in cols:
    sql = f'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `{col}` IS NULL'
    cursor.execute(sql)
    # process the results of the query


Thanks for your solution, however I wanted to keep this strictly within SQL and call the script within Python for other reasons.

MySQL doesn't have a good way to loop through a list of columns, since it has no list-like data type. And to do any kind of loop you need to write a stored procedure that constructs the query dynamically with PREPARE.

@KidSudi, That is not possible with database. You should use a programming language like python to do (like how we did)

@Barmar, Upvoted your ans as it is almost similar to the way I did

@Barmar thank you for that. What would the stored procedure solution look like?

Since MySQL doesn't have arrays, you would have to store the list of columns in a table. You would use a cursor to iterate over a query from that table. Then construct the query in a string variable, use PREPARE STATEMENT and EXECUTE to execute the queries.

Is that enough of a general direction for you? Please make an attempt and I'll help yuo fix it if it doesn't work.

Taken sqlite example. But queries will be similar  for other sequential database like mysql or mssql.
The following will execute queries for each column being null. And for each query, it'll create a 2d list and store as the value of the dict. The key names of the dict will be the respective column names. You can process the data from the dict
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

dct = {}

columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']

for column in columns:

    qry = f'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE {column} IS NULL'

    cursor.execute(qry)

    # fetch the results
    r = cursor.fetchall()
    
    # create a 2d list of each colum
    dct[column] = [list(row) for row in r]

conn.close()

For mysql, you can use mysql.connector module and for MSSQL you can use pyodbc module for connection.
